# Material UI - slider event handler

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I am working with a [vanilla Material UI slider](https://material-ui.com/components/slider/#small-steps) and am trying to build an event handler to display the current value of the slider as `h2` text above the input.

From my understanding, an event handler such as this at the state-level should suffice.

```
     handleInput = input => e => {
      this.setState({[input]: e.target.value});
      console.log(e)
      const aum = e.target.value;
      this.setState({aum});

      const data = [...this.state.data];
      const index = 4;
      data[index].aum = e.target.value;
      this.setState({data});

  }
```

However it's not working and after inspection, the slider actually doesn't use `target.value` but something called `aria-valuenow`. I then, naively changed the function to:

```
     handleInput = input => e => {
      this.setState({[input]: e.target.aria-valuenow});
      console.log(e)
      const aum = e.target.aria-valuenow;
      this.setState({aum});

      const data = [...this.state.data];
      const index = 4;
      data[index].aum = e.target.valuenow;
      this.setState({data});

  }
```

However, that returned an error as it seems it's an invalid JSX expression to have a hyphenated term in that spot. Not exactly sure what is the right approach from here.

Here is my state, just in case it's relevant (note I'm referencing the key `aum` with my slider):

```
  state = { 
    selectBoxes: [
        {id:1, strategies:['Large cap','Small cap', 'Dividend','Offshore','IPO']},
        {id:2, strategies:['Large cap','Small cap', 'Dividend','Offshore','IPO']},
        {id:3, strategies:['Large cap','Small cap', 'Dividend','Offshore','IPO']},
    ],
     data: [
      {quarter: "2Q20", aum: 100},
      {quarter: "3Q20", aum: 200},
      {quarter: "4Q20", aum: 300},
      {quarter: "1Q21", aum: 400},
      {quarter: "2Q21", aum:500}
    ],
    aum:500
 }
```

### Question

How to point to `target.aria-valuenow` in my event handler if it's an "invalid expression"?

Comment: What handler are you passing to the `onChange` event? The `onChange` event accepts a handler with the signature `(event, number) => void`. See https://material-ui.com/api/slider/

Comment: @pablo I'm passing the key to the state value, (hopefully): `onChange={props.handleInput('aum')}`

Comment: Your second functions where you only accept `e` as the argument, add second parameter. Name it `value`. That should have value you are looking for. Ex: `handleInput = input => ( e, value ) => {...}`